# QCamera::start gives mysterious "failed to start" log message

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia, qcamera

It's just plain luck my program is so simple, so I eventually found out what causes the mysterious log message. My program log looks like this:

```
Debugging starts
failed to start
Debugging has finished
```

Which happens after:

```
camera = new QCamera(QCameraInfo::defaultCamera());
// see http://omg-it.works/how-to-grab-video-frames-directly-from-qcamera/
camera->setViewfinder(frameGrabber = new CameraFrameGrabber());
camera->start();
```

The `start()` method causes this message in console. Now the meaning of the message is obvious, what it's not very helpful. What steps should I take to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I wonder how could two users vote to close as unclear, yet have no clarification questions... Does anyone else here not understand the question? I'm not sure what should I elaborate on, it seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasons for this might differ, but in my case it was simply because I provided invalid `QCameraInfo`. The culprit is that `QCameraInfo::defaultCamera()` might return invalid value if Qt fails to detect any cameras on your system, which unfortunately happens even if cameras are present.